# Must declare the scalar variable "@Sid" in gridview while getting single record

Tags: asp.net

while i'm trying to get single record from database table,based on login user details. i'm getting error,let me know where i'm doing wrong.

```
string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbcs"].ConnectionString;
SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection((cs));
cn.Open();
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Student_Details where Sid=@Sid", cn);  
SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
DataSet ds = new DataSet();
da.Fill(ds);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: check my answer you will get solution.

Answer (score 0):

Why you are executing query for select statement - `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` not require..

You have to pass parameter value also

```
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sid", sid);
```

Comment: i'm not getting grid view after compiling,just displaying a label which i mentioned for heading to that grid, and not getting any error.

Comment: string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbcs"].ConnectionString;
            SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection((cs));
            cn.Open();                                                                 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Select * from Student_Details Where Sid=@Sid", cn);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Sid", Sid);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);           
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);        
            GridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
            GridView1.DataBind();

Comment: @DineshReddy Yes it should be work, check your table Student_Details which Sid you are passing is there or not?

Comment: yes in my table i have that column, i created table with these columns Sid,name,fathername,mothername,email phone,address,previousclass,uid. when user logged in based on that login user Sid i'm trying to get that user details. i think some mistake i'm done. check once and let me know bro.

Comment: @DineshReddy check your gridview's auto generate columns property = true.? if not then do and check again..

Comment: I tried that already brother, but i dnt understand what is wrong in my code. :(

Comment: <asp:GridViewID="GridView1"runat="server"AutoGenerateColumns="true"BackColor="White"BorderColor="#999999"BorderStyle="None"BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" GridLines="Vertical"> <Columns>                  <asp:BoundField DataField="sid"HeaderText="Sid"SortExpression="sid" /<asp:BoundFieldDataField="name"HeaderText="Name"SortExpression="rname" /> ..like that all columns details added as i mentioned above cmnt

Comment: @DineshReddy for testing Remove <Columns> <asp:BoundField DataField="sid"HeaderText="Sid"SortExpression="sid" /<asp:BoundFieldDataField="name"HeaderText="Name"SortExpression="rname" />...... </Columns> and also keep debug point on DataSet and check data is there or not ?

Answer (score 0):

you missed this lines:

`cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("sid", User.Identity.Name)`

and also  `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();` is not necessary.

Comment: i'm not getting gridview after compiling,just displaying a label which i mentioned for heading to that grid, and not getting any error.